# How do I fill these holes, fill space without information, and deal with overlapping meshes

Tags: mesh

Hello user forums and those interested,

I have scanned a brick using a 3D scanner and the mesh it provided has lots of holes, overlapping mesh, and it missed the extruded interior of the holes.
How can I fill the random holes more efficiently than selecting edges and filling the holes? How do I deal with the overlapping faces? How should I fill the extruded interior?

[image: Random holes]
[image: Lack of information]
[image: Overlapping faces]
[image: Rendering]

Answer (score 1):

Try the [remesh modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier). This will generate an entirely new manifold mesh made exclusively of quads.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @gandalf3. It looks as though it helped with the surface although losing detail. But it has now filled the holes totally and I need a method of rebuilding how they should look... I feel like I should somehow build two cylinders + a rectangular prism and somehow fill the walls with that. Not sure


http://i.imgur.com/i51V5TW.jpg

Comment: @Peter Not sure what you mean..? I can't help but think it might be easier to model the object from scratch, instead of trying to fix the scan..

Comment: @Peter adding to gandalf3's coment, you might want to recreate your object. Look into retopologizing techniques using a shrinkwrap modifier. You can keep the level od detail you want with proer topology and no gaps.