# Script to remove faces with significantly different normals

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, faces, normals

I have a mesh imported from a Structure Scanner that has some dirty mesh sections. I have a script that imports, orients and simplifies the mesh to this:

[image: Outside of structure]

However, looking from the inside shows that some faces are facing inwards, causing problems for another program along to process:

[image: Inside showing some normals are incorrect]

The scanner seems to double up some faces causing these problems. I can get away with deleting the erroneous faces/vertices (leaving holes to be filled in blender or the next stage), but I can't figure a way to detect these areas and remove them.

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87113/40463) solution from another question looked promising, but, firstly, I can't get the script to work and, secondly, it takes an average of the whole selection which wouldn't work on this nearly hemispherical shape.

Is there perhaps a simpler way of removing and correcting these erroneous points, CATIA has "clean non manifold triangles"?

Close up of one of the problems:

[image]

Comment: Answered based on title and script part. For cleaning suggest looking at [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/how-do-i-fill-these-holes-fill-space-without-information-and-deal-with-overlap)

Comment: Just wanted to add that there is an operator `bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()`

Answer (score 0):

**A script to select verts based on the angle between normal and radial vector.**

---

An alternative script than the one shown in [question link.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87113/40463)

In the case where the object is spherical, , after [changing the object origin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object?s=5%7C50.0488) to the centre of the base ring if hemisphere (or where sphere centre would be), can then check the angle between vert  normal and vert coordinate (since `vert.co` is  also the vector from (0, 0, 0) origin). If it was a perfect sphere, all these angles would be zero.

Test script to run in edit mode. (In vertex selection mode) Change the 90 degree value of `angle_check = radians(90)` to suit.  The script only selects verts with an angle of norm to radial outside `angle_check`.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
angle_check = radians(90)
for v in bm.verts:
    v.select = v.normal.angle(v.co) > angle_check

'''
# or by faces
for f in bm.faces:
    f.select = f.normal.angle(f.calc_center_median()) > angle_check

'''
bm.select_flush(False)
me.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [3D Printing Toolbox](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) add-on.

It checks your mesh for any bad geometry that would prevent proper printing, which includes intersecting faces, non-manifold edges, bad contiguous edges and so on.